# starting work after midnight

Tags: human-resources, payroll

If you have someone starting a night shift but they don't start until after midnight, what day of the week would that be considered? Example: they start at 12:30am

The reason it might not be so obvious is that there can be weekend differentials, so a Sunday shift can pay differently from a Monday shift.  An employee is claiming it is a Sunday shift since it is starting Sunday night.

Comment: Is there a reason why it wouldn't be the obvious answer: the actual day that their shift starts and ends?

Comment: An employee is questioning that even though they start after midnight that it is still the night. They are saying that they should be paid for Sunday night even though they start on Monday am.

Comment: @Julie - I edited your question based on your comment, and I hope I got the gist of it correct.  With that additional information, I don't think it would be considered off-topic.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek It is still off-topic as company policy.

Comment: @Julie, Are you allowed to create/change your own company policy? If so, tell us. That would be one way to get your question re-opened. But we'd also need to know what your underlying motivation was in resolving this matter. Are you trying to be fair? Are you afraid that your employees won't volunteer for your worst shifts?

Comment: Why was my comment deleted and a later comment that is basically the same from Joe Strazzere not deleted?  My comment was start day is company policy and therefore VTC.

Comment: @Paparazzi Regarding bonuses for weekend shifts there might as well be local laws, but it's hard to tell without knowing where the OP is located.

Answer (score 6):

If you are the employee ask your supervisor or HR. They should have a document that tells shift workers how to correctly fill out their time card. In some cases you may need to enter specific start and end time in order to assign shift premiums to specific hours.

If you are HR this should be a potion of your employee documents. You will have to compare your proposed guidelines to national/local labor laws and any union contracts.

While it does seem simple to say 12:30 am is assigned to the day they start. The big question is when does the Sunday shift premium and overnight premiums begin and end when somebody starts work at 12:30 AM Monday, what happens if that is when their shift ends?